# "I won't do it like you do", what does this mean?

Tags: modal-verbs, negation

Does this mean that "I don't do it, and you don't do it", or "i don't do it, and you do it"?

And what does "I won't do it like you don't" mean?

I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I won't do it like you do.

The meaing is

> I **will not** do it like you do.
>   I **will not** follow your example.

An example:

> I see you include no comments in your C++ code. That's bad. I **won't** do it like you do. I will always comment my code so that other programmers could understand it.

But note that the use of the pronoun **it** could indicate two slightly different meanings

1. I will not do the thing(s) you do.
2. I will do the thing(s) you do, but in a different way.

Comment: I see, so it means "you do something, and i won't do the same thing."

Comment: @aborealscene: yes

Comment: The meaning is that 'I will do it, but I'll do it differently from the way that you do it.'. See Khan's answer for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 3):

My way of doing it is different from yours.

It doen't at all mean what the OP understands.  The word "like" has been used as a conjunction in the sentence, which means "in the same way or manner as". So "I won't do it like you do" means that I won't do it in the same way as you do.